Explanation on Takesaki Theorem V.1.41
I am studying the following theorem from Theory of Operator Algebras I, Takesaki,

(Theorem V.1.41, pg. 308) If $e$ and $f$ are two projections on a Hilbert space $\mathfrak{H}$, and if $\mathscr{M}$ is the von Neumann algebra generated by $e$ and $f$, then,

(i). $\mathscr{M}$ is of type $I$.
(ii). there exists uniquely a central projection $z \in \mathscr{M}$ such that $\mathscr{M}z $ is of type $I_2$, and $\mathscr{M}(1-z)$ is abelian and $\dim \mathscr{M}(1-z)\le 4$.
I didn't understand how the author concluded these two from the discussion above this theorem. What I understood from that discussion is that:
Let $e, f\in \mathscr{M}$ such that $e\wedge f=e^{\perp}\wedge f=e \wedge f^\perp=e^\perp\wedge f^\perp =0$ (such pair is called 'generic'). Then we can show that $\mathscr{M}\equiv \mathscr{M}_e \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathfrak{H})$ and there $e$ and $f$ has the following form:
$$
e = \begin{pmatrix}
1 && 0\\
0 && 0
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } f = \begin{pmatrix}
c^2 && cs\\
cs && s^2
\end{pmatrix}; 0\le c, s\le 1; c^2 + s^2 = 1; c,s \in \mathscr{M}_e
$$
Q1. From the above how can we conclude that $\mathscr{M}$ is of type $I$?
Q2. How the general case for any two $e, f$ follows from the above 'generic' $e, f$?
Q3. Also how did they get that $z$ in (ii)?
Thank you.

From $\def\n{\wedge}\def\CC{\mathbb C}$
$$\tag1
1=e\n f+e\n f^\perp+e^\perp\n f+e^\perp\n f^\perp+e_0\vee f_0
$$
we get that these five projections are pairwise orthogonal. The first four are also minimal and central, since for instance $e(e\n f)=f(e\n f)=e\n f$. This makes $e_0\vee f_0$ central, too. Let us call these five projections $q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4$, and $p$ respectively. It follows that
$$\tag2
M=pMp\oplus \bigoplus _{k=1}^4\CC q_k.
$$
Takesaki's computations with $e_0,f_0$ show that $pMp\simeq M_{e_0}\otimes B(\CC^2)$. Since $pMp$ is generated by $e_0$ and $f_0$ and $c,s$ are selfadjoint commuting operators, it follows that $M_{e_0}\subset W^*(c,s)$ is abelian (more details below).
So $pMp$ is a type I$_2$ von Neumann algebra. And taking $z=I_2\oplus 0$ in $(2)$, we have that $Mz=pMp$ is type I$_2$ and $M(1-z)=\bigoplus _{k=1}^4\CC q_k$ is abelian with dimension at most $4$.

Proof that $M_{e_0}$ is abelian. The algebra $M_{e_0}$ is the $1,1$ corner of the algebra generated by
$$
e_0=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad
f_0=\begin{bmatrix}c^2&cs\\cs&s^2\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $c,s$ are commuting selfadjoints and $c^2+s^2=1$. Looking at $e_0f_0e_0$ and $e_0(1-f_0)e_0$ we get that $c,s\in M_{e_0}$. Conversely, $M_{e_0}$ is the closure of the span of words of form $e_0 W (e_0,f_0)e_0$, where $W(e_0,f_0)$ is any word on $e_0,f_0,1-e_0,1-f_0$. As $e_0,f_0$ are projections, there are not that many possibilities for $e_0 W (e_0,f_0)e_0$: they are precisely the words  $1$ and $c^{2n}s^{2m}$ for $n,m$ non-negative integers. Hence $M_{e_0}=W^*(c^2,s^2)=W^*(c,s)$.

Proof that $e\n f$ is minimal. We have $e(e\n f)=f(e\n f)=e\n f$. The algebra $W^*(e,f)$ is the closure of the span of words on $e$ and $f$. For any such word $w$, we have $w(e\n f)=(e\n f)w =e\n f$. It follows that for any polynomial $p(w)$ we have $p(w)(e\n f)\in \mathbb C\,(e\n f)$. The same will be true for any linear combination of words, and for their limits. In particular, for any projection $q\in W^*(e,f)$ you have $q (e\n f)=e\n f$ or $q(e\n f)=0$. That is, $e\n f$ is minimal.

I didn't get why $e\wedge f$ is minimal in $M := W^*(e, f)$? here $e, f$ are any arbitrary projections.

Also why is $M_{e_0} \subset W^(c, s)$? If this is true then, since $c, s \in M_{e_0}$, we'd get $W^(c, s)\subset M_{e_0}$, i.e., $M_{e_0}  \subset W^*(c,s)$. Is this the case?

I have included more details.
